# xmonad io binding not working

Tags: haskell, xmonad

One of the key bindings in my `~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs` file is this:

```
((modMask .|. shiftMask, xK_q), io (exitWith ExitSuccess))
```

So, I tried to use this pattern to make a binding that would cycle through keyboard layouts. I have `cycleKLayouts :: IO ()`, which works perfectly when run from `ghci`. Then, I write:

```
((modMask, xK_minus), io cycleKLayouts)
```

This compiles fine, but when I try the key, the only thing that happens is that the current terminal and the one the mouse is under (both Terminology) flash faintly. This is different to what happens with an unbound key, which just passes the letter through to the application.

I've also tried `liftIO`, rather than `io`, with the same results. I also have a direct `spawn` binding:

```
((modMask, xK_equal), spawn "setxkbmap -v gb -variant colemak")
```

which works, but provides a different behaviour. (`cycleKLayouts` runs `setxkbmap` at some point).

---

Edit: definition of `cycleKLayouts`:

```
module Keyboards where
import System.Process
import Control.Applicative
kLayouts = [("gb(colemak)", "UK-CO")
          ,("gb", "UK-QW")
          ,("us(colemak)", "US-CO")
          ,("us", "US-QW")]
getKLayout :: IO String
getKLayout = f . (!! 4) . lines <$> readProcess "setxkbmap" ["-print"] []
    where
        f ('+':cs) = g cs
        f (_:cs) = f cs
        f _ = ""

        g ('+':_) = ""
        g (c:cs) = c:g cs
        g _ = ""

getNextKLayout :: IO String
getNextKLayout = do
    l <- getKLayout
    let kLayoutNames = map fst kLayouts
    let f (x:y:xs) = if x == l then y else f (y:xs)
        f _ = head kLayoutNames
    return $ f kLayoutNames

setKLayout :: String -> IO ()
setKLayout l = readProcess "setxkbmap" ["-v", l] [] >> return ()

cycleKLayouts :: IO ()
cycleKLayouts = setKLayout =<< getNextKLayout
```

Answer (score 2):

Rewriting `cycleKLayouts` in such a way that it has type `X ()` and runs your command with `spawn`, certainly should help. I guess the problem lies in the way that `cycleKLayouts` runs the command. Probably in result `setxkbmap` doesn't have access to your environment variables, or gets forked and then terminated.

If you post the source of `cycleKLayouts` I probably would be able to give more specific answer.

Update:

Well, I've just tried to add this to my configuration:

```
((modMask, xK_a), liftIO (readProcess "setxkbmap" ["-print"] "" >>= putStrLn))
```

Whenever I was pressing `M-a` an error message "waitForProcess: does not exist (no child process)". I can't really explain a reason for that, but I guess it has to do with the way Xmonad spawns keybinded actions (probably it's a potential bug).

However, replacing `readProcess` to `runProcessWithInput` (from [Xmonad.Util.Run](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Util-Run.html)) solved the problem completely:

```
 ((modMask, xK_a), liftIO (runProcessWithInput "setxkbmap" ["-print"] "" >>= putStrLn))
```

Try this to make sure that we catched on the same problem.

Comment: I just liked the idea of the keyboard layout not depending upon xmonad, so that the same script could be used in other WMs. I'd also like to understand why it doesn't work.