# How do I use the output of readProcess in an xmonad keybinding?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

Ok, so some time ago I was thinking of basing the effect of a keybinding in my xmonad based on the output of a script on my box. I eventually decided not to do that for unrelated reasons but I did recently try to do something similar just as an exercise in learning Haskell.

So, given the function:

```
test = readProcess "echo" ["-n", "gvim"] []
```

This throws up because test returns IO String and spawn expects a String.

```
((modm, xK_y), spawn ("xmessage " ++ test))
```

Ok. That's cool. I get it that IO operations are unpredictable and so they should be kept separate. Fine. So I did some poking around online and got to this (dropped the xmessage and just want to pass the output of test by itself):

```
((modm, xK_y), liftIO test >>= spawn)
```

This is worse. It annoyingly compiles but nothing happens when I try out the binding. (I also replaced it with just spawn "xmessage test" and that worked)

So, then I thought "Maybe there's something wrong with my function" so I repl it but from GCHi I get "gvim" which is correct. So then I write it to a haskell file:

```
main = test >>= putStrLn
test = readProcess "echo" ["-n", "gvim"] []
```

Also works correctly.

So, where did I go wrong?

EDIT: Solution was to use `runProcessWithInput` instead of `readProcess`. 
Related link: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5212 [xmonad io binding not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26562522/xmonad-io-binding-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Apparently the solution (see the comments below) is to use `readProcessWithInput`

**Original Answer**

You said that:

```
liftIO test >>= spawn
```

didn't work, but how about:

```
liftIO test >>= (\m -> spawn ("xmessage " ++ m))
```

Also note that the string returned by `readProcess` likely will have a newline at the end, and that may be affecting things.

Some more things to try in this vein:

```
return "gvim" >>= (\m -> spawn ("xmessage " ++ m))


import Data.Char

do { m <- liftIO test;  spawn ("xmessage " ++ (filter isAlpha m)) }
```

The first one should succeed since it is equivalent to `spawn "xmessage grim"`. The second one will strip any newlines (indeed, any non-letters) from the output of `test`.

Some further things which might shed light on what is going on:

1. Create a script called `/tmp/report` with these contents:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   ( date; echo "/tmp/report was called with args" "$@") >> /tmp/output
   ```
2. Make `/tmp/report` executable.
3. Run `/tmp/report` and verify that two lines was appended to `/tmp/output`
4. In your monad config, make the action `spawn "/tmp/report A"`. Test the action by seeing if the expected line is appended to `/tmp/output`.
5. Try making the monad action this:

   ```
   liftIO (readProcess "/tmp/report" ["B"] "") >> spawn "/tmp/report A"
   ```

   (Note we are using `>>` here, not `>>=`.) When you trigger the action you should see a report line for the `B` call and also one for the `A` call.

Based on what you see in the file `/tmp/output` you should be able to determine whether the `readProcess` command is even being executed as well as the `spawn` command is triggering.

Comment: No difference, unfortunately.

Comment: Added some new ideas to try out.

Comment: I edited my question, but with the current example, the echo with the -n does not seem to be returning a newline at least when I try it on a standalone program. Going to try the other suggestions.

Comment: No joy :-/ The first one did indeed succeed but the second one resulted in no response to my binding.

Comment: Added some more things to try.

Comment: Apparently, the issue was with how xmonad treats its children. The solution is to replace readProcess with runProcessWithInput