# Haskell XMonad configuration using readProcess

Tags: haskell, xmonad

I'm trying to configure XMonad without actually understand the 
Haskell syntax.

I run a gnome session with xmonad on top. I want to press mod-p to 
toggle the gnome-panel:

- if the gnome panel is not running I want to launch it.
- if the gnome
  panel is already running I want to kill it

I thought that this would do it:

```
startgpanel :: X ()
startgpanel = do
  gp <- readProcess "pidof" ["gnome-panel"] ""
     if (length gp)
     then spawn "killall gnome-panel"
     else spawn "gnome-panel"

  ...
 ((myModMask, xK_g), startgpanel)
  ...
```

But I get an error:

```
xmonad.hs:169:12:
    Couldn't match expected type âX (t0 a0)â
                with actual type âIO Stringâ
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      gp <- readProcess "pidof" ["gnome-panel"] ""
    In the expression:
      do { gp <- readProcess "pidof" ["gnome-panel"] "";
           if (length gp) then
               spawn "killall gnome-panel"
           else
               spawn "gnome-panel" }
```

I dont really understand the Monad concept, I just want
to do some IO, but it seems very complex...

Comment: it looks like you had a dollar sign in the error message but not in the code you posted

Comment: The  error is the same with $ or not. I wonder what "X (t0 a0)" means...

Comment: try adding `liftIO $ readProcess "pidof" ...`. `liftIO` is able to convert `IO a` computations into `X a` computations

Comment: If you read carefully the error it becomes quite clear. The line that produces the error is `gp <- readProcess ...` and the error says that the type of that thing is `IO String` while the compiler expects an `X something`. The problem is that `readProcess` is an operation in a *different* monad from `X`, and as haoformayor suggests `liftIO` allows you to use that operation inside the `X` monad.

Comment: I added liftIO and indeed the error message goes away, thanks. However it seems that readProcess doesnt run: If i run xmonad inside Xephyr I can see:
xmonad-x86_64-linux: waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes)
waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes)... Any idea?

Comment: Answers should not go into the question body. If you want to post your own answer you can do so. If you'd like ErikR to provide the actual code to implement the solution you should comment and request this on his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you need to use `liftIO`.

Also consult the discussion of this SO question:

[How do I use the output of readProcess in an xmonad keybinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37174160/866915)

Instead of `readProcess` you might need to use `readProcessWithInput`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your IO action in `liftIO` to run it in the X monad.
Also you cannot just use the result of `length` as an `Bool` for the if statement, as it returns an `Int`:

```
startgpanel :: X ()
startgpanel = do
  gp <- liftIO $ readProcess "pidof" ["gnome-panel"] ""
  if (length gp > 0)
    then spawn "killall gnome-panel"
    else spawn "gnome-panel"
```

Comment: The error dissapears, thanks, however the "pidof gnome-panel" doesnt seem to execute: 
xmonad-x86_64-linux: waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes) waitForProcess: does not exist (No child processes)..

Answer (score -1):

Because of all the nastiness xmonad does with processes, I would propose you move the whole darn bunch of logic into the shell; bind a key to this operation:

```
spawn "pidof gnome-panel && killall gnome-panel || gnome-panel"
```

Look ma, no `do`!